# Backgound/Text resizing issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a screen design where the text is above the wave.

This is the original design.

[image: Original Design]

but when I try to do it in different Android screen size, I get this

[image: Overlapping]

The text is not part of the background.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to work around this issue? Should I make the text part of the background?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a rather design-orientated question, then I want to share my thoughts:

Embedding text into images is something that I as a developer would try to avoid. This got several reasons:

- Text embedded in images cannot be scaled using the built-in Android text size option. When using a regular `TextView`, it is recommended to specify the text size using `sp` standing for scalable pixels, which take the user preference for Android-wide text size into account. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dip-dp-and-sp) question for more details.
- Text embedded in images cannot be found by the Android Accessibility framework (for example, Text-To-Speech for blind people).
- Images that have text embedded are really bad to maintain from a developer perspective. You need to provide several resolutions, several languages, and optionally different images for bright or night mode in Android. This leads to a huge amount of resources that is unhandy.
- You need to carefully test and configure images with included text, because there might be devices with unusual resolution leading to distorted images or text.

I'd personally prefer using a regular `TextView` for the text and let the surrounding layout handle the position of the `TextView`. `ConstraintLayout` is really flexible doing that. You could also just use two or three different layouts to separately configure in each layout on how the `TextView` should be positioned. Depending on your development framework, Android could even automatically pick the right layout, depending on the device size.

Hope this gives you an idea.